# Implementing shortcut keys in a webpage

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I was thinking of implementing shortcut keys in a pet web application, I am developing for me. I am using c# and asp.net.

I have seen very few web-sites( frankly I remember only g-mail), which have shortcut keys.

Has anyone ever implemented shortcut keys for a web application, if yes how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Shortcut keys often don't work the same way across all browsers.  And they are awful on Opera.  And most users won't use them.  The only thing I'd bother with on most sites is buttons for next and prev, and I'd also make the alt tag say "next" or "previous" to assist browsers with fast forward.

Comment: Just noticed that bitbucket implements shortcuts, such as "r d" to view downloads, "?" to show all shortcuts. You need to have focus on the web page (i.e. not on the search box).

Comment: check my sollution it will help you . i am use javascript (keycode) for shortcuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accesskeys are useless, but visit [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20140601065313/http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/accesskey.html) if you insist on using them.  Much better to use this than javascript, though the ways of accessing access keys varies across browsers.  The advantage of this over ugly Javascript solutions is that it leaves it up to the browser and the user's browser settings to handle them.

Answer (score 6):

[Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) is an excellent JavaScript library for handling shortcut keys.

Based on how I've seen other apps (Gmail, JIRA) use shortcut keys, and based on my own experience, I would make a couple of suggestions:

- Interfering with browser shortcut keys is a real possibility.  The most reliable way to avoid this is to use unmodified letters (i.e., <kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> or <kbd>Alt-A</kbd>).
- Keyboard shortcuts are relatively rare for web sites, so they suffer from poor discoverability.  Since they're not very discoverable, you'll need to add, e.g., tooltips or unobstrusive hints letting users know that they exist.  Keyboard shortcuts seem to be most useful for web applications, like Gmail and JIRA, that are expected to be used heavily; otherwise, there's just not enough opportunity or benefit to learning them.

Answer (score 4):

If you enable this feature, **make sure you can switch it on and off** - be aware that your shortcuts may interfere or conflict with the built-in shortcuts that many of the assistive software packages out there (i.e. Jaws), and **can be counterproductive in terms of accessibility**.

Answer (score 3):

[Handling Keyboard Shortcuts in JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript)

But I understand why few sites use it - this way has many difficulties. And encourage you to not use it too. Or not to make it as main feature.

Answer (score 3):

In order to implement this you need to register your required keyboard key combinations with JavaScript. It's like registering action listeners in C# for certain events. First URL I found on Google here seemed to have a good overview: [Handling Keyboard Shortcuts in JavaScript](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/).

Once keyboard events are registered you can then use the JavaScript to invoke AJAXy (technically JSON calls I think) operations on your ASP.net backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    if (window.captureEvents) {
        window.captureEvents(Event.KeyUp);
        window.onkeyup = executeCode;
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent('onkeyup', executeCode);
    }

    function executeCode(evt) {
        if (evt == null) {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        var theKey = parseInt(evt.keyCode, 10);
        switch (theKey) {
            case 35:  // End
                document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click();
                //document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnHome').click(); 

                break;
            case 36:  // F8
                document.getElementById('btnreset').click();
                break;
            case 120:  // F9
                // document.getElementById('Button1').click();

                break;
            case 87: //w
                if (window.event.altKey)
                    document.getElementById('buttonid').click();
                break;
        }
        evt.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

</script>


             <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button"  />
           </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Do you want to give more description?

Answer (score -3):

```
use this javascript on your master page this work using keycode.........


------------------------------------------ 

var isfocused=false;    
   document.onkeydown = overrideKeyboardEvent;
document.onkeyup = overrideKeyboardEvent;
var keyIsDown = {};
var get_focused="";
function overrideKeyboardEvent(e){
  switch(e.type){
    case "keydown":
      if(!keyIsDown[e.keyCode]){
        keyIsDown[e.keyCode] = true;
        // do key down stuff here
       if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                var t = new Array;
                t = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                var n = "1";
                for (var r = 0; r < t.length; r++) {
                    if (t[r].type == "checkbox") {
                        var i = document.cookie.split(";");
                        var s = y = i[0].substr(i[0].indexOf("=") + 1);
                        if (s.toLowerCase().indexOf("active") != -1) {
                            if (n == "2") {
                                document.getElementById(t[r].id).focus();
                                document.cookie = "aa" + "=" + t[r].id;
                                return false
                            }
                            if (t[r].id == s) {
                                n = "2"
                            }
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById(t[r].id).focus();
                            document.cookie = "aa" + "=" + t[r].id;
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         if( e.keyCode==115)
        {    e.preventDefault();
             var c = new Array();
             c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
             for (var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
             {
                 if(c[i].type=='submit' && c[i].value=='Submit' ||  c[i].type=='submit' && c[i].value=='Summary Report' )
                 {  
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById(''+c[i].id+'').click();
                  }
             }

           return ;

        }
         if( e.keyCode==27 )
        {
           window.location = document.referrer;
        }
        if( e.keyCode==46 )
        {
           var c=new Array();
           c=document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
           for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
           {
                if(c[i].onclick!=null)
                {
                    if(c[i].onclick.toString().indexOf('OnUserSelected')!=-1 && c[i].onclick.toString().indexOf(''+get_focused+'')!=-1)
                    {       
                         var children =new Array();
                         if(c[i].innerHTML.indexOf('remove')!=-1)
                         {
                         children = c[i].innerHTML.split('remove');
                         var gg=children[1];
                         var get1=new Array();
                         get1=gg.split('id="');

                        // document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_hidden111').value='1111';
                         var a= document.getElementById(''+get1[1]+'remove').click();
                         return false;
                       //__doPostBack(''+get1[1]+'remove','');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            children = c[i].innerHTML.split('delete');
                         var gg=children[1];
                         var get1=new Array();
                         get1=gg.split('id="');

                        // document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_hidden111').value='1111';
                         var a= document.getElementById(''+get1[1]+'d`enter code here`elete').click();
                         return false;
                        }


                    }
                }
           }
        }
         if( e.keyCode==112 )
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            var c=new Array();
            c=document.getElementsByTagName('a');

            for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
            {
                if(c[i].innerText.indexOf('Add New')!=-1 || c[i].innerText.indexOf('Back to')!=-1)
                {
                    window.location=''+c[i].href+'';
                }
            }

        }
         if( e.keyCode==113)
        {
            if(get_focused!="")
            {
                var c=new Array();
                c=document.getElementsByTagName('input');

                for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
                {
                if(c[i].type=='hidden')
                  {

                    if(c[i].id.indexOf('hidden111')!=-1)
                    {
                    document.getElementById(''+c[i].id+'').value='00';
                    document.getElementById(''+c[i].id+'').value=get_focused;
                         __doPostBack(c[i].id,"");
                    }
                  } 
                }


            }
        }
         if (e.keyCode == 38) {

                var t = new Array;
                t = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                var n = "1";
                for (var r = 0; r < t.length; r++) {
                    if (t[r].type == "checkbox") {
                        var i = document.cookie.split(";");
                        var s = y = i[0].substr(i[0].indexOf("=") + 1);
                        if (s.toLowerCase().indexOf("active") != -1) {
                            if (t[r].id == s) {
                                n = "2"
                            }
                            if (n == "2") {
                                var f = 0;
                                while (f == 0) {
                                    if (t[r - 1].type == "checkbox") {
                                        f = 1
                                    } else {
                                        r--
                                    }
                                }
                                document.getElementById(t[r - 1].id).focus();
                                document.cookie = "aa" + "=" + t[r - 1].id;
                                return false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    break;
    case "keyup":
      delete(keyIsDown[e.keyCode]);
      // do key up stuff here
    break;
  }

  //e.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
function disabledEventPropagation(e) {
    if (e) {
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation()
        } else if (window.event) {
            window.event.cancelBubble = true
        }
    }
}
document.body.setAttribute("onunload","getdeleted()");
function getdeleted()
{
     document.cookie="aa" + "=" +"";
}
0
function OnUserSelected(source,eventArgs) {

                   if(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_hidden111').value!='1111')
                   { 

                      var hdnValueID = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_hidden111';
                    try
                    {
                   document.getElementById(hdnValueID).value =source;

                    document.getElementById(hdnValueID).value = eventArgs;
                    __doPostBack(hdnValueID, "");
                    }

                    catch(errorr)

                    {
                        alert(errorr);
                    }
                  }
                else
                {
                   get_focused =eventArgs;

                     document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_hidden111').value='';


                }
                    }
```