# ASP textbox from right-left / left-right

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

How Can I write from right to left after pressing Alt+Shift

and writing from left to right by pressing Alt+shift inside asp textbox

(Different Languages)

Any Ideas ??!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing shortcut keys in a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368542/implementing-shortcut-keys-in-a-webpage)

Comment: You mean just writing from right to left / left to right in the same language?

Basically you can use the event "onkeydown" and manipulate the value of the text box using javascript/jquery. (or the "change" asp.net event but its much slower)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .aspx markup add the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleKeyDown(e) {
    var altPressed = 0;
    var shiftPressed = 0;
    var evt = (e == null ? event : e);

    altPressed = evt.altKey;
    shiftPressed = evt.shiftKey;

    if (altPressed && shiftPressed) {
        var textDemo = document.getElementById('TextBoxDemo');
        textDemo.classList.toggle("otherDir");
    }

    return true;
}
</script>

<style>
  .otherDir {direction:rtl}
</style>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDemo"  CssClass="otherDir" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

In page load event, add the following line:

```
TextBoxDemo.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "handleKeyDown()");
```

The above line will add the client-side event handler for pressing ALT-SHIFT in the HTML input rendered.  It will toggle the direction each time the keyboard combo is pressed.